# Android Multiple Choice List SQLite

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How can i save the info from a multiple choice listview into the database? I want to save the status of a item from a list. For instance, if i have 2 items checked i want to save this status in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure fegol,

I assume you already set up the multiple choice listview. (if not, please check online there are heaps of them http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-multiple-choice-example).

Here I'd like to give you some hint on data-saving problem.

Basically, there are two common choices. **The first** is to use getCheckedItemIds() or getCheckedItemPositions() on your listview (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds()).

**The second one** which is more flexible is to write a custom adapter. You can use isChecked() to check whether the checkbox was checked, and then save the status into your hashmap. Then you can get all status of checkboxes at the last.

I put some pseudo-code for the second approach for you. Hope this helps.

```
    ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    // TODO: put some empty data into checkList  



    private OnItemClickListener myListItemClickListener = new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {


        if(checkList.get(position)){
            checkList.set(position, false);
        }else{
            checkList.set(position, true);
        }

        ((mAdapter)mList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }



    class mAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (checkList.get(position)){
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi ThinknChris. Can you show me some tutorials of how to save checked items from listview into database? thanks and regards